# Force close onClick of ImageButton, can't figure out why

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to do a simple animation with ImageButtons, when I set it up so that if I simply touch the screen, it works just fine, but if I try to do it onClick, the app just closes.

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/plus1"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="RunAnimations" 
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gears1"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/gears"
        android:textSize="42sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

translate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:zAdjustment="top" >
</translate>

<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000">
</alpha>
</set>
```

The main Activity:

```
    public class AnimationtestActivity extends Activity  {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
        private void RunAnimations() {
            Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
            View ib = findViewById(R.id.gears1);
            ib.clearAnimation(); 
            ib.startAnimation(a);     
        }
    }
```

edit:

I fixed the 
    private void RunAnimations(View view)

But it's still force closing

edit 2: Contents of logcat

```
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method RunAnimations(View) in the activity class com.test.AnimationtestActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'plus1'
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3026)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: RunAnimations [class android.view.View]
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3019)
03-08 13:07:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(29270):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: kindly check your method. you are trying to cast ImageButton to View on 2nd line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework isn't finding your click handler method because it has the wrong signature. Declare it like this:

```
public void RunAnimations(View view) {
    . . .
}
```

Comment: I fixed that, but It's still giving me a force close. Any other ideas?

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?could you please post the logs?

Comment: I posted the logcat in the question, thanks for the help so far

Comment: @LucasMarcelli - You still need to change the method signature to be `public`.

Comment: @TedHopp Oh dear, I feel like a right idiot now. I didn't even notice I had it set to private. Thanks so much, it works now. I wish I had enough rep to give you a vote...